# django-social auth example app giving ValueError(Missing backend entry)

Tags: django, django-socialauth, socialauth

While using the example app of the django social-auth the user can login to the social accounts but when they are redirected back to our portal it gives a value error Missing backend entry.

Actual error:

> [01/Nov/2013 15:49:21] "GET /login/twitter/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
>   [01/Nov/2013 15:49:25] "GET /complete/twitter/?oauth_token=ZETJZMsQQhdWzawgrt8xI
>   9DMEfyCb2N8jpXkVpYfC8&oauth_verifier=zmIXXCAfa2foLolK1v8PIBMQLlrQD6uEYiJ8fwjT14HTTP/1.1" 302 0
>   Internal Server Error: /login/error/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
>       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_social_auth-0.1.14py2.7.egg\social\apps\django_app\utils.py", line 31, in wrapper
>   redirect_uri=uri, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "..\social_auth\views.py", line 19, in load_strategy
>       return get_strategy(BACKENDS, STRATEGY, STORAGE, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_social_auth-0.1.14-py2.7.egg\social\strategies\utils.py", line 10, in get_strategy
>   raise ValueError('Missing backend entry')ValueError: Missing backend entry

Comment: did you define in your settings the redirection after login example: SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='/url_name/'

Comment: The exception happens because `/complete/twitter/` is redirecting to `/login/error/` (so there might be an error happening during complete process), but `/login/error/` is being treated as `/login/<backend>/` URL and looking for an authentication backend named `error`, which doesn't exists.